# Why does the next.js Script tag with the beforeInteractive strategy don't load thirdParty script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I try to understand how the next.js Script tag with the strategy beforeInteractive works. For testing i just used lodash. But i keep getting a **ReferenceError: _ is not defined**. I thought when a script is loaded with beforeInteractive it should be globally available inside my page Component since it get injected into the initial Html from the server and i could use it for example in the useEffect hook to alter a div.
Can someone explain to me why it's not working or what i'm doing wrong?
I don't installed it via npm because im trying to figure out how it works.

I have a simple _document.js and i added a Next.js script tag with the strategy beforeInteractive to this _document.js. The next.js docs says:
*This strategy only works inside _document.js and is designed to load scripts that are needed by the entire site (i.e. the script will load when any page in the application has been loaded server-side).*

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
        <Script
          src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.20"
          strategy="beforeInteractive"
        ></Script>
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Then i have a simple page Component inside the pages folder. I added the getServerSideProps function to use ServerSideRendering.

*If you export a function called getServerSideProps (Server-Side Rendering) from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps.*

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const TestComponent = () => {
    const [change,setChange] = useState('not changed');

    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log(_);
        setChange(_.join(['one','two'],' - '));
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Test</title>
            </Head>
            <div>{change}</div>
        </>
    );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
      props: {},
    }
  }

export default TestComponent;
```

**Update**

Seems like it is indeed a bug which is fixed but not released yet
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37098

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting aside the fact that you should be importing Lodash as a node module, there does seem to be an issue when using `next/script` in `_document` (no matter what the external script actually is).

It turns out this is a Next.js bug that has been addressed in this [PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/37000) in pre-release version [v12.1.7-canary.8](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v12.1.7-canary.8). To fix the issue in your project simply update Next.js to version >=12.2.0 (`npm install next@latest`).

---

As an alternative, you can use the `<script>` tag directly in the `_document`'s `<Head>` with the `defer` property. This closely matches what the `next/script` would output.

```js
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
    return (
        <Html>
            <Head>
                <script
                    type="text/javascript"
                    src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.js"
                    defer
                ></script>
            </Head>
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    )
}
```

Comment: it works with the script tag and defer. But i still don't understand the beforeInteractive strategie . Could you give me an example when and how to use the beforeInteractive strategie? The docs say it's good for Bot detectors and Cookie consent managers but i don't understand how to use it though since it should be injected in the initial html from the server.

Comment: @JimbeiLaw Using `next/script` with `beforeInteractive` strategy achieves what the above code does: inject the script into `<head>` with `defer`. To test it, try moving the `Script` component you have in `_document` to `_app` instead. Although not recommended in the docs (hence why I didn't include it in my answer), it should work and correctly add the script in the `<head>`.

Comment: ok it works when i put the next.js Script tag into the _app.js with beforeInteractive. But the docs say: "Outside of the _document, it's not possible to guarantee the timing or ordering of beforeInteractive scripts" so why does it not work with the _document.js when the docs explicitly state to do it in _document.js.

Comment: @JimbeiLaw Only explanation I can see is it must be a bug. Might be worth raising with the Next.js team.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, I'm failing to see virtually any reason you'd want to do this, when you can (and should) simply use install it to `node_modules`. You're also going to possibly run the risk of the bundle having issues if the library type isn't a module and the next configuration requires a module.

### Solution based on the question:

There's two ways.
Firstly, see the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) on this exact thing.

**Please use the above method mentioned in the docs.**

*If that's not an option for whatever reason...*

The second is a *less than ideal*, but working solution.

Create a folder for your static files. Ex: `<root>/static/js/hello.js`. Then in your `_document` file,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/hello.js"></script>
```

Comment: What method do you referring to in the docs? There are 4 strategies. I tried lazyOnload and afterInteractive and it worked like expected. I didn't tried the web worker because it isn't stable yet. But i cant get it to work with the beforeInteractive strategie. Can you point me to some good example how this strategie works? I couldn't find any good sources. I know it make not much sense to not install the package via Npm but i'm just trying to get a better understanding whats happening and why it won't work. I read the docs multiple times. For static files i need the public folder in the root.