# Having issues loading Scripts in my NextJS React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to load some scripts in my NextJS application. I have followed the procedures outlined in the NextJS documentation but it doesn't seem to work in my application.

The link to the documentation is, https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script.

I load the scripts in the _document.js file like this.

_document.js

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import Script from "next/script";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    // Run the React rendering logic synchronously
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        // Useful for wrapping the whole react tree
        enhanceApp: (App) => App,
        // Useful for wrapping in a per-page basis
        enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
      });

    // Run the parent `getInitialProps`, it now includes the custom `renderPage`
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return initialProps;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <Script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"
            id={`jquery-1${+new Date()}`}
            strategy="beforeInteractive"
          ></Script>
          <Script
            src="/webflow.js"
            id={`webflow-1${+new Date()}`}
            strategy="beforeInteractive"
          ></Script>
          <Script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"
            id={`webfont-1${+new Date()}`}
            strategy="beforeInteractive"
          ></Script>
          <Script strategy="lazyOnload" id={`load-font-1${+new Date()}`}>
            {`WebFont.load({  
              google: {    
                families: ["DM Sans:regular,500,700"]  
            }})`}
          </Script>
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

I also tried this by putting the scripts in the `Head` tag but it was the same result.

_document.js

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import Script from "next/script";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    // Run the React rendering logic synchronously
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        // Useful for wrapping the whole react tree
        enhanceApp: (App) => App,
        // Useful for wrapping in a per-page basis
        enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
      });

    // Run the parent `getInitialProps`, it now includes the custom `renderPage`
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return initialProps;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <Script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"
            id={`jquery-1${+new Date()}`}
            strategy="beforeInteractive"
          ></Script>
          <Script
            src="/webflow.js"
            id={`webflow-1${+new Date()}`}
            strategy="beforeInteractive"
          ></Script>
          <Script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"
            id={`webfont-1${+new Date()}`}
            strategy="beforeInteractive"
          ></Script>
          <Script strategy="lazyOnload" id={`load-font-1${+new Date()}`}>
            {`WebFont.load({  
              google: {    
                families: ["DM Sans:regular,500,700"]  
            }})`}
          </Script>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

I confirmed that the scripts were not working by checking the network tab and also as there functionalities that were meant to work on the website and dependent on the scripts were not working.

Comment: Try to paste your `<script>...</script>` in _app.js and if needed `<link>...</link>` (.css files) in _document.js

Comment: check : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-google-tag-manager/pages/_app.js

Comment: This is for inline scripts.

Comment: I did this on a project for jquery and bootstrap

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Why does the next.js Script tag with the beforeInteractive strategy don't load thirdParty script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332560/1870780)?

Comment: @juliomalves, this loads the scripts but not creates a new error. The error description says, "Unhandled Runtime Error - Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

Comment: And also, How do I load an inline script using the new method from the refernce link. I have something like this, 

<script type="text/javascript" defer>
  {`WebFont.load({  
    google: {    
      families: ["DM Sans:regular,500,700"]  
  }})`}
</script>

but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's what I have but it doesn't reflect the changes, even after adding the strings.