# How to load google maps api using nextjs?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, next.js

How do you load and use the google maps api using Nextjs?

1 - How do you load the api? I've tried to load it in _document.js:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import Script from 'next/script'

const source = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&libraries=places`

const Document = () => {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <Script type="text/javascript" src={source} strategy="beforeInteractive" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}

export default Document
```

2 - How do you reference the API?

Something like: ? `window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService().getPlacePredictions()`

But I get an error that google is undefined

I have also tried using npm libraries but none seem to work.
[react-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete)
[use-places-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-places-autocomplete)

Comment: There's a Next.js bug when using `next/script` in `_document` with `beforeInteractive` strategy. See [Why does the next.js Script tag with the beforeInteractive strategy don't load thirdParty script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332146/why-does-the-next-js-script-tag-with-the-beforeinteractive-strategy-dont-load-t).

Comment: That being said, you probably do not need to use `beforeInteractive` strategy to load Google Maps script. Try loading the script using the [`afterInteractive`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#afterinteractive) or [`lazyOnload`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#lazyonload) strategies inside your `_app` instead.

Answer (score 8):

The Google Maps team provides a quick, helpful tutorial "[How to load Maps JavaScript API in React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e-5QHpadi0)" that uses the [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) package in a Next.js project.  The code snippet below comes from the [repo](https://github.com/leighhalliday/google-maps-intro) linked by the tutorial's author, [@leighhalliday](https://github.com/leighhalliday).

**1. How to load the Google Maps JavaScript API**

- Pass your API key to [useLoadScript](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#!/useLoadScript)
  (a React hook provided by [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) that loads the Maps API)
- Once loaded, return an instance of the [GoogleMap](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#!/GoogleMap) component

  - In this simplified example, the initial location is memoized.   But see the second example below for how you might use in conjunction with the Google [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview)
  - You can optionally also add a `Marker` to the map

```js
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";

export default function Home() {
 const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
   googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
 });

 if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;
 return <Map />;
}

function Map() {
 const center = useMemo(() => ({ lat: 44, lng: -80 }), []);

 return (
   <GoogleMap zoom={10} center={center} mapContainerClassName="map-container">
     <Marker position={center} />
   </GoogleMap>
 );
}
```

**2. How to add Autocomplete with the Places + Google Maps API's**

The Google Maps team provide a second [tutorial](https://youtu.be/BL2XVTqz9Ek) to implement search + autocomplete in your map that leverages the [use-places-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-places-autocomplete) package.  You can also find the full code in [@leighhalliday](https://github.com/leighhalliday)'s repo [example](https://github.com/leighhalliday/google-maps-intro/blob/main/pages/places.js).