# What is proper way to import script files in Next Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js

I was trying to use a template of bootstrap, CSS files are imported properly by I'm not able to import JS. I came to know that in Next Js you can import them in useEffect hook. But still, it gives an error that the script not found. Here is my code,

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    import("../public/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js");
    import("../public/lib/js/bootstrap.min.js");
    import("../public/lib/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js");
    import("../public/lib/js/jquery-ui.min.js");
    import("../public/lib/js/jquery.slicknav.js");
    import("../public/lib/js/mixitup.min.js");
    import("../public/lib/js/owl.carousel.min.js");
    import("../public/lib/js/main.js");
  }, []);
  return (
      <>
      <Head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Ogani, unica, creative, html"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>

        {/* Font */}
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
        {/* CSS */}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/elegant-icons.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/nice-select.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/slicknav.min.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>


      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
   );
  }
  export default MyApp;
```

Here is my directory structure,

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfPe4.png)

After the suggestion is used _document.js inside the pages directory to include local scripts but still they aren't included when the page is rendered.

**pages/_document.js code is below,**

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
            {/* Site Tag */}
            <Script src="lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
            <Script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
            <Script src="lib/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
            <Script src="lib/js/jquery-ui.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
            <Script src="lib/js/jquery.slicknav.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
            <Script src="lib/js/mixitup.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
            <Script src="lib/js/owl.carousel.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
            <Script src="lib/js/main.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#overview and this: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script to see if they solve your problem. They explain the correct ways to include scripts in a NextJS project.

Comment: @ChizaramIgolo I've tried that already. Script tag loads from 3rd party CDN etc. I want to load the script files from my public directory. There is no example of loading from the public directory with a Script tag.

Comment: Okay, I get you. For the benefit of those who may ask the same question in the future, please see my answer.

Comment: @ChizaramIgolo please check the above I edited and posted as per your answer.

Comment: Using the `beforeInteractive` strategy in `_document` currently doesn't work as expected. See [Why does the next.js Script tag with the beforeInteractive strategy don't load thirdParty script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332146/why-does-the-next-js-script-tag-with-the-beforeinteractive-strategy-dont-load-t) for a solution/workaround.

Comment: @juliomalves I've tried adding using script tag with deferring attr. But after adding like this when I load my website it gives an error,

"Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

Tags are added like this in _document.js body, 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" defer></script>

Comment: That may related to how you're using those third-party libraries in your codebase. Probably worth asking about that in a different question with more details and a proper [mre].

Comment: @juliomalves what's improper the way I asked this question everything is clear and precise. "That may related to how you're using those third-party libraries in your codebase" yes I know that, but what's the solution?

Comment: @juliomalves still i posted a new question ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72602177/next-js-fails-to-load-third-party-script-in-document-js

Comment: What I meant was, the new issue is most likely not related to the scripts imports, but to how you're using the code that is imported by the scripts, hence why a new question may be better suited to address that.

Answer (score 5):

### Update:

Changed `beforeInteractive` to `lazyOnload`. You may also use `afterInteractive`.

---

Say you have a local script file: `myscript.js` that you are trying to include in your NextJS project, to include it:

1. Place the script file in your `/public` folder and
2. In your page component add:

---

**Inside page component:**

```
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <div>
       {/* Other stuff */}
        <Script
          src="myscript.js"
          strategy="lazyOnload"
        />
    </div>
  )
}
```

NextJS will know to look for scripts referenced without a URL prefix like `https` in the public folder.

Learn more about the `<Script>` component and other load `strategy`s here:

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#overview and https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script

Comment: let me try if it works or not. I'll get back to you in a while, thanks.

Comment: it's not working by using Document, see my code please,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FJfbuQHnBLHU8HT7DmNmmsyMYnfiniXl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please place it within the `<body>` tag, not the `<Head>` tag. Also, you don't need `<NextScript/>` when using `<Script/>`.

Comment: `<NextScript/>` can and should still be used even if you're using the `Script` component in `_document`.

Comment: I've used it inside body now and also removed <NextScript/>.

Comment: @ChizaramIgolo  I've moved Script tags to the body but still it's not loading any script there. But when I replace my 'Script' tags with 'script' tags it will load successfully with an error "hydration failed.....".

Comment: Sorry, please change `beforeInteractive` to `lazyOnload`.